# Parsing JSON POST PHP, unable to generate object

Tags: php, urlencode, json, blitline

I've done this many times before with various SAAS services, but I can't parse the supposedly JSON responses I'm getting from [Blitline](http://www.blitline.com/docs/api) image processing's API.

Here's what I do to handle the POST:

```
$body=@file_get_contents('php://input');

print_r($body); 

results=%7B%22original_meta%22%3A%7B%22width
```

OR

```
$body=rawurldecode($body);

print_r($body); 

results={"original_meta":{"width ...
```

When I go to print `$body->original_meta->width`, I get an empty string. You'll realize I didn't `json_decode()` the `$body` but that's because that returns an empty string too.

Removing the `results=` with `substr($body, 8)` doesn't help either.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why don't you start by removing the error suppression and see if that does anything

Comment: I don't understand your code blocks...is "results=" part of your code? Or is that the response? If the latter, is "results=" part of the response, or is that just your way of showing us what the code resulted in?

Comment: It looks like you are perhaps getting not getting a JSON string POSTed to the script, but rather a query string with parameter `results` with a URL-encoded JSON string value. Perhaps in this case you should actually be getting your value from `$_POST` (that is of course if request is coming in with form-encoded content type header.

Comment: Why are you dealing with the raw post? Seems you just want `$data = json_decode($_POST['results'])`.

Comment: I was just going to say it would make sense to deal with `$_POST` instead of reading input.

Comment: @MrCode you are correct `json_decode($_POST['results'])` works. Thanks so much. Can you post this as an answer. I also figured out how to do it my way too and I will submit that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment: the POST data is standard x-www-form-urlencoded data so there's no need to access the raw POST data. You can simply access the `$_POST` array that contains the URL decoded data:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['results']);
echo $data->original_meta->width;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is pretty ugly but it works...

```
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');

$body=rawurldecode($body);

$body=substr($body, 8); 

$body=json_decode($body);

echo $body->original_meta->width; //1936
```

Comment: I think another option would be to use `parse_str($body, $data); json_decode($data['results']);`.